# Deleting duplicates in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, duplicates, element

Here is the code. It's just deleting the half of duplicate elements from an array and others are to remain there. don't know what is the problem. need assistance thank you.

```
 int[] count_list = { 10, 20, 10, 30, 30, 40, 20, 50, 90, 60, 80, 70, 80, 90 };
 int l = count_list.Length;   
 for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
 {
      for (int j =i + 1; j < l;)
      {
           if(count_list[j] == count_list[i]){
                for (int k = j; k < l; k++)
                {
                     count_list[k] = count_list[k + 1] ;
                     l--;
                }

           }
           else{
                j++;
           }
      }       
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < count_list.Length; i++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(count_list[i]);
      //  Console.WriteLine("name");
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete Duplicate from an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055668/delete-duplicate-from-an-array)

Comment: This question shows no evidence of any debugging effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're decrementing `l` with each iteration inner-most `for`-loop. Try rewriting it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < l;)
    {
        if(count_list[j] == count_list[i]){
            l--;
            for (int k = j; k < l; k++)
            {
                count_list[k] = count_list[k + 1] ;
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

And remember to call `Resize` if you want to shrink the array back down at the end:

```
Array.Resize(ref count_list, l);
```

However, this is a lot of unnecessary work. I'd strongly suggest using a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or Linq's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
count_list = count_list.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Distinct` method to produce a new array without duplicates;

```
int[] noDupes = count_list.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Distinct method instead:

```
var newArray = oldArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

This will obviously create a new array, instead of editing the original one.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816001/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-in-c)